# Calculating a "lookat" Rotation Vector

Tags: c++, glm-math

I've already got some code that uses the `glm` function `lookat` in order to point a camera at a target (it's a third person chase cam kind of thingy).

This works fine, but I need it in slightly different form.

The problem with the `glm::lookat` function is that you provide it an eye position vector, the target position vector and then the "up" rotation vector and it spits back a full matrix.

But I only want the rotation vector - the orientation - from where the camera is to look at the target. I need the output to be a `vec3` rotation vector, not a full-blown `mat4` matrix.

The reason being, in case you're wondering, is that I've already got classes - used for objects in the scene - which store a position vector and a rotation vector, then you call `getMatrix()`, as and when you need the matrix for that.

That's just the general way my code works and I want to get the camera working on the same basis. But I need a version of `lookat` that just sets the rotation vector to look at a target (same inputs - camera position vector, target position vector, "up" vector - but an output of a rotation vector, not a full-blown 4x4 matrix).

The creation of the matrix from the position and rotation is, like, a separate stage that happens later (I've not mentioned scale because, basically, it's always just 1.0 in my code so far).

So I guess what I'm looking for is a version of `lookat` that takes the same inputs, but the output is `vec3` rotation vector.

Just the angles, not the fully composed 4x4 matrix, with everything baked in (because trying to extract everything back out of such a matrix would be a much harder problem than just directly calculating what I want in the first place).

Edit: To try to be more precise, I have code something along these lines (example inline for readability, actually separate .h and .cpp in reality):

```cpp
class Entity
{
    protected:
        glm::vec3    position;
        glm::vec3    orientation;
        glm::vec3    scale;

    public:
        Entity(void)
        {
            position = glm::vec3(0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
            orientation = glm::vec3(0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
            scale = glm::vec3(1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
        }

        void setPosition(glm::vec3 nposition)
        {
            position = nposition;
        }

        void setOrientation(glm::vec3 norientation)
        {
            orientation = norientation;
        }

        glm::mat4 getMatrix(void)
        {
            glm::mat4 matrix = glm::mat4(1.0);
            matrix = glm::translate(matrix, position);
            matrix = glm::rotate(matrix, orientation.x, glm::vec3(1.0, 0.0, 0.0));
            matrix = glm::rotate(matrix, orientation.y, glm::vec3(0.0, 1.0, 0.0));
            matrix = glm::rotate(matrix, orientation.z, glm::vec3(0.0, 0.0, 1.0));
            matrix = glm::scale(matrix, scale);

            return matrix;
        }
};
```

The idea is that the game logic sets / manipulates the position and orientation of the entity. But then, for rendering, we call `getMatrix` and this then supplies the `glm::mat4`.

Currently, the camera is not an `Entity` and I just use `glm::lookat` directly to get a matrix for rendering. But I'd like to include the camera as an entity, but to make it fit this scheme, I need to decompose it into this same two stage process.

Set the `glm::vec3` called `orientation` to look at a target point (with a particular "up" vector) - the position of the camera is already stored in the class - so that when I call `getMatrix` for rendering later, I get the same `glm::mat4` that `glm::lookat` spat out.

Comment: If you just want to rotate your camera... Take the line of sight (-z axis of your camera?). Take the vector from camera position to target position. Compute the cross product between the two vectors -> that's your rotation axis. Compute the angle between these two vectors -> that's your rotation vector. Now you can determine the rotation matrix as angle-axis-matrix (or do the rotation in whatever way you prefer).

Comment: @Scheff'sCat  "Compute the angle between these two vectors -> that's your rotation vector". Well, yes, but the question I'm asking is how do I compute that?

Comment: Angle between 2 vectors `v1` and `v2`: `angleInRadiant = std::acos(glm::dot(glm::normlaize(v1), glm::normlaize(v2))`

Comment: Maybe I'm not understanding something. But `acos` returns a single value, yet there are three angles (pitch, yaw, roll) to define a 3D rotation. Do I do this to each component individually? Or just pitch and yaw, because roll doesn't matter and should always be "up"? Maybe these are very basic questions, I'm sorry, but I can't find any resources on this particular subject - it all goes to matrices immediately, as with `glm::lookat`, without intermediate steps to help me understand.

Comment: To clarify, I've done this sort of thing before but in 2D, where you use atan2 to derive the angle between points. But there is only one angle in 2D to be worried about. If we ignore roll (defined as always "up") then there's two angles in 3D. I'm clearly confused here, I'm sorry.

Comment: There are multiple ways to describe rotations: Euler-angles (what you mentioned as Yaw-Pitch-Roll), Axis-Angle, Quaternions, etc. All of them have a corresponding rotation matrix (as long as the rotation is limited to <= 360°). FYI: [AxisAngle to Matrix](https://www.euclideanspace.com/maths/geometry/rotations/conversions/angleToMatrix/index.htm)

Comment: Then I guess I want Euler angles, because - as I've shown in the code I added - I create the matrix from pitch, yaw and roll values.

Answer (score 0):

The orientation of the view matrix is the upper left 3x3 of the 4x4 view matrix. This can be obtained by constructing a `glm::mat3` from a `glm::ma4`:

```cpp
glm::mat4 view = glm::lookAt(eye, target, upVector);
glm::mat3 viewR = glm::mat3(view);
```

The view matrix transforms from world space into view space. Therefore, it is the inverse matrix of that matrix that determines the orientation and position of the camera. If you want the 3x3 matrix of the camera orientation you need to get the [`inverse`](https://glm.g-truc.net/0.9.9/api/a00371.html#gaed509fe8129b01e4f20a6d0de5690091) matrix:

```cpp
glm::mat3 viewR = glm::mat3(view);
glm::mat3 cameraR = glm::inverse(viewR);
```

Given the camera position (`eye`), the camera target (`target`), and the up vector (`upVector`), the orientation matrix can be calculated in a right-handed system where the x-axis is to the left, the y-axis is the up-vector, and the z-axis is points in the opposite direction of the line of sight, as follows:

```cpp
glm::vec3 zAxis = glm::normalize(eye - target);
glm::vec3 xAxis = glm::normalize(glm::cross(upVector, zAxis));
glm::vec3 yAxis = glm::cross(zAxis, xAxis);
glm::mat3 cameraR = glm::mat3(xAxis, yAxis, zAxis);
```

Comment: Thanks, this looks like useful information. But the output there seems to be a 3x3 matrix, when I'm looking for just the angles, in a `vec3`.

Comment: Okay, I've edited the original post to try to bring some more clarity to what I'm doing and am looking for. I hope this helps. If I've annoyed you, this was entirely unintentional on my part. I'm fairly new to asking questions on here, I apologise if I'm not quite doing it right.